# Database structure for saving subgroups in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I made a post a while back and got a lot of comments about how bad my code was. So now im asking you to help me on how do it better. I'm trying to save subgroups in mysql. This is how the subgrouping can look:

```
Bosses
    Minibosses
    Wannabe bosses
         Denied bosses
    Future bosses
Sales
    Private
    Companies
HR
Support
```

I might not add them in this order. Say 2017-01-01 i add all but "Denied bosses", and then 2017-02-01 add it. How would you this up in mysql? If you could show me an example at http://sqlfiddle.com/ I would really appreciate it.

Also, how would you go about fetching these results so that I can easily print it in a dropdown? I cant use optgroup in html because i need to be able to press the top groups. The problem lies in displaying them on my site properly

Answer (score -1):

Smart table for your soloution can be like this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/369172/6/0

:-)

SQL for main groups:

`select * from group where parent_id is null;`

SQL for subgroup:

`select * from group where parent_id = :parentGroupId;`

Comment: ive got it setup like this right now. how would you go on about displaying them in proper order together? top groups alone is easy and so is subgroups. but the problem lies in displaying them correctly together